# Restful Web service - java.lang.NoSuchMethodError concat(Ljava/lang/Iterable;Ljava/lang/Iterable;)Ljava/lang/Iterable

Tags: java, web-services, rest, web

I am trying one restful web service example so when I am going to hit url that time I am getting below exception

```html
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: jersey.repackaged.com.google.common.collect.Iterables.concat(Ljava/lang/Iterable;Ljava/lang/Iterable;)Ljava/lang/Iterable;
    org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.ConfigHelper.getContainerLifecycleListener(ConfigHelper.java:92)
    org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:172)
    org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:363)
    javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)
    org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:505)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:956)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:423)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1079)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:625)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:316)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
```

Below are the Jars i am using

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This sort of error is usually caused by having an older version of Guava (or even google-collections) on the classpath in addition to the newer version you're trying to use.

This answer should help you find it and eliminate it.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/12044668/5856415

Answer (score 0):

Get rid of all the jars you currently have in the image, and download the [distribution (RI Bundle)](https://jersey.java.net/download.html). Add *all* the jars from this distribution into your project.

The problem you are currently facing is 1. you have a bunch or mismatched versions, and 2. you don't even have all the required jars.

Comment: Thanks peeskillet :)