# How do I get Jersey 2.6 working with Tomcat 6 and Java 1.6?

Tags: java, tomcat, jersey, jersey-2.0, java-6

I'm trying to use Jersey (verson 2.6) with Tomcat 6 running on Java 1.6. It should be possible but is throwing errors and I'm not sure how to configure it properly or what libs to include.

Jersey Libs I have: https://maven.java.net/content/repositories/releases/org/glassfish/jersey/bundles/jaxrs-ri/2.6/jaxrs-ri-2.6.tar.gz

This seems to indicate it can be made to work with Servlet 2.5 (which is what Tomcat 6 uses): https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/modules-and-dependencies.html

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: jersey.repackaged.com.google.common.collect.Iterables.concat(Ljava/lang/Iterable;Ljava/lang/Iterable;)Ljava/lang/Iterable;
        org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.ConfigHelper.getContainerLifecycleListener(ConfigHelper.java:86)
        org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:169)
        org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:358)
        javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:212)
        org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
        org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:293)
        org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:861)
        org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:612)
        org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:503)
        java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
```

Comment: what error does it throw

Comment: `java.lang.NoSuchMethodError concat(Ljava/lang/Iterable;Ljava/lang/Iterable;)Ljava/lang/Iterable`

Comment: this is java path problem not jersey plug in. Try few things. Look at the build path of your jdk and look at your library is pointed to your path. look at similar issue from: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35082976/restful-web-service-java-lang-nosuchmethoderror-concatljava-lang-iterablelja

Comment: @user3659052 I'll look at that but I'm not sure it is. I think it might be expecting a newer/older version of that lib?

Comment: have you check the maven to make sure all the dependent jar has been added?

Comment: Are you adding any other Jersey jars besides the ones that come in the tarball you linked to?

Comment: @user3659052 I'm not using maven to build the project. I'm just importing the libs into an IntelliJ project

Comment: @peeskillet No, just the jars that were inside the `api`, `ext` and `lib` folders

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get this working properly, you need:

1. The 2.6 Jersey files from https://maven.java.net/content/repositories/releases/org/glassfish/jersey/bundles/jaxrs-ri/2.6/jaxrs-ri-2.6.tar.gz
2. Genson (Helps with JSON of objects that aren't "obvious" for JSON): http://owlike.github.io/genson/
3. Include all those jars in your `web-inf/lib` folder (either directly, or via your IDE's compile/deploy configs)
4. Make sure there's no other versions of ANY of the jars or their classes anywhere in the Web application's classpath (my IDE was retaining old versions of Guava)