# how to solve Restful Web service error on tomcat startup?

Tags: rest, tomcat7, guava

I recently added the Jersey Jars for using rest and tomcat is failed to start with the following error:

```
Oct 01, 2018 12:13:11 AM org.glassfish.jersey.internal.inject.Providers checkProviderRuntime
WARNING: A registered provider org.glassfish.jersey.jaxb.internal.JaxbParamConverterBinder is constrained (via @ConstrainedTo) to SERVER runtime but does not implement any provider interface usable in the runtime. Due to constraint configuration problems the provider org.glassfish.jersey.jaxb.internal.JaxbParamConverterBinder will be ignored. 
Oct 01, 2018 12:13:12 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
SEVERE: StandardWrapper.Throwable
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: jersey.repackaged.com.google.common.collect.Iterables.concat(Ljava/lang/Iterable;Ljava/lang/Iterable;)Ljava/lang/Iterable;
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.ConfigHelper.getContainerLifecycleListener(ConfigHelper.java:92)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:172)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:363)
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1230)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1174)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1066)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:5370)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5668)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1700)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1690)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

The jars list where the Jersey jars are included as well:
[image]

Thanks.

Comment: Use Maven......

Comment: Hi Paul, I was able to solve the compatibility problems by removing Jersey and make use of resteasy with seam out of the box (basically removing jars and reattached jars). As for your advise about Maven, I'll need to convert my project to Maven at some stage YES. But for now it looks too difficult to convert the large jars list to a working POM file with all the dependencies. For most jars I don't know which dependencies entries should be added.

Answer (score 0):

These types of error sometimes indicate that you have older and newer versions of the libraries you are using in your class path. There might be a mismatch among the guava libraries you are using. See this related question's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35082976/restful-web-service-java-lang-nosuchmethoderror-concatljava-lang-iterablelja).

Maybe you should consider using Maven for handling project dependencies.

Comment: I've already googled and saw the answer you linked. I'm using Jersey 2.27 and the guava version is 18.0 as you can see in the picture. I know that the error indicate about mismatch but I need to know exactly,

Comment: Try to remove guava jar, since you have already imported  jersey-guava which repackages the guava classes.

Answer (score 0):

There are somes cases that cause that error, eg:

1. You don't have any jar file that contains the class jersey.repackaged.com.google.common.collect.Iterables . But as i know that your file jersey-guava-2.25.1.jar has it already. So this case is ignored.
2. The above jar file is damaged so it can't load that class. So you can delete that jar and replace by other properly jar.
3. There are more than one that class in your all libraries. Maybe other other jar contain that class too. So you can check this case on your IDE and remove this conflict.

Hope this help!

Comment: I've found that this method appear on both  jersey-guava-2.25.1.jar and jersey-common.jar but removing the jersey-common.jar  I got different error: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.glassfish.jersey.internal.inject.AbstractBinder

Comment: At least, you have known about the root cause. You should use jersey-common version same as jersey-guava's