# Ant Build that publishes to artifactory on jenkins gives the error: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.common.collect.Iterables.find

Tags: jenkins, ant, jenkins-plugins

When building a `ant` project that has the checkbox `Ant/Ivy-Artifactory Integration` checked in the config in the jenkins job using the jenkins artifactory plugin version 2.5.0, I get the following error:

```
/foo/ant/dependency.xml:19: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.common.collect.Iterables.find(Ljava/lang/Iterable;Lcom/google/common/base/Predicate;Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;
at org.jfrog.build.extractor.trigger.ArtifactoryBuildInfoTrigger.findModule(ArtifactoryBuildInfoTrigger.java:292)
at org.jfrog.build.extractor.trigger.ArtifactoryBuildInfoTrigger.getOrCreateModule(ArtifactoryBuildInfoTrigger.java:305)
at org.jfrog.build.extractor.trigger.ArtifactoryBuildInfoTrigger.collectDependencyInformation(ArtifactoryBuildInfoTrigger.java:100)
at org.jfrog.build.extractor.trigger.ArtifactoryBuildInfoTrigger.progress(ArtifactoryBuildInfoTrigger.java:80)
at org.apache.ivy.core.event.FilteredIvyListener.progress(FilteredIvyListener.java:42)
at org.apache.ivy.core.event.EventManager.fireIvyEvent(EventManager.java:64)
at org.apache.ivy.core.resolve.ResolveEngine.resolve(ResolveEngine.java:343)
at org.apache.ivy.core.resolve.ResolveEngine.resolve(ResolveEngine.java:195)
at org.apache.ivy.Ivy.resolve(Ivy.java:507)
at org.apache.ivy.ant.IvyResolve.doExecute(IvyResolve.java:326)
at org.apache.ivy.ant.IvyTask.execute(IvyTask.java:277)
at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:291)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor6.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:392)
at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.performTasks(Target.java:413)
at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeSortedTargets(Project.java:1399)
at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTarget(Project.java:1368)
at org.apache.tools.ant.helper.DefaultExecutor.executeTargets(DefaultExecutor.java:41)
at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTargets(Project.java:1251)
at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.runBuild(Main.java:811)
at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.startAnt(Main.java:217)
at org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher.run(Launcher.java:280)
at org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:109)
```

reading other questions here some suggests that I could have 2 versions of `guava` in my classpath.

I verified and I have only one.

```
/foo-lib/aether-api-1.0.2.v20150114.jar
/foo-lib/aether-impl-1.0.2.v20150114.jar
/foo-lib/aether-spi-1.0.2.v20150114.jar
/foo-lib/aether-util-1.0.2.v20150114.jar
/foo-lib/backport-util-concurrent-3.1.jar
/foo-lib/build-info-api-2.6.0.jar
/foo-lib/build-info-client-2.6.0.jar
/foo-lib/build-info-extractor-2.6.0.jar
/foo-lib/build-info-extractor-gradle-4.4.0.jar
/foo-lib/build-info-extractor-ivy-2.6.0.jar
/foo-lib/build-info-extractor-maven3-2.6.0.jar
/foo-lib/build-info-vcs-2.6.0.jar
/foo-lib/classworlds-1.1-alpha-2.jar
/foo-lib/commons-codec-1.4.jar
/foo-lib/commons-io-2.0.1.jar
/foo-lib/commons-lang-2.4.jar
/foo-lib/commons-logging-1.1.1.jar
/foo-lib/groovy-all-2.1.6.jar
/foo-lib/guava-18.0.jar
/foo-lib/httpclient-4.2.5.jar
/foo-lib/httpcore-4.2.5.jar
/foo-lib/ivy-2.4.0.jar
/foo-lib/jackson-core-asl-1.5.1.jar
/foo-lib/jackson-mapper-asl-1.5.1.jar
/foo-lib/jdom-1.1.jar
/foo-lib/jzlib-1.1.2.jar
/foo-lib/maven-artifact-manager-2.2.1.jar
/foo-lib/maven-deploy-plugin-2.8.2.jar
/foo-lib/maven-model-3.1.0.jar
/foo-lib/maven-plugin-registry-2.2.1.jar
/foo-lib/maven-profile-2.2.1.jar
/foo-lib/maven-project-2.2.1.jar
/foo-lib/maven-repository-metadata-3.1.0.jar
/foo-lib/plexus-container-default-1.0-alpha-6.jar
/foo-lib/plexus-container-default-1.0-alpha-9-stable-1.jar
/foo-lib/plexus-utils-1.0.2.jar
/foo-lib/plexus-utils-3.0.10.jar
/foo-lib/xpp3_min-1.1.4c.jar
/foo-lib/ant-antlr.jar
/foo-lib/ant-apache-bcel.jar
/foo-lib/ant-apache-bsf.jar
/foo-lib/ant-apache-log4j.jar
/foo-lib/ant-apache-oro.jar
/foo-lib/ant-apache-regexp.jar
/foo-lib/ant-apache-resolver.jar
/foo-lib/ant-apache-xalan2.jar
/foo-lib/ant-commons-logging.jar
/foo-lib/ant-commons-net.jar
/foo-lib/ant-jai.jar
/foo-lib/ant-javamail.jar
/foo-lib/ant-jdepend.jar
/foo-lib/ant-jmf.jar
/foo-lib/ant-jsch.jar
/foo-lib/ant-junit.jar
/foo-lib/ant-junit4.jar
/foo-lib/ant-launcher.jar
/foo-lib/ant-netrexx.jar
/foo-lib/ant-swing.jar
/foo-lib/ant-testutil.jar
/foo-lib/ant.ant-contrib-1.0b3.jar
/foo-lib/ant.jar
/foo-lib/ant.svnkit-1.1.2.jar
/foo-lib/ant.svntask-1.0.8.jar
/foo-lib/asm.asm-3.0.jar
/foo-lib/asm.asm-analysis-3.0.jar
/foo-lib/asm.asm-commons-3.0.jar
/foo-lib/asm.asm-tree-3.0.jar
/foo-lib/asm.asm-util-3.0.jar
/foo-lib/asm.asm-xml-3.0.jar
/foo-lib/aspectj.aspectjmatcher-1.6.10.jar
/foo-lib/aspectj.aspectjrt-1.6.10.jar
/foo-lib/aspectj.aspectjtools-1.6.10.jar
/foo-lib/aspectj.aspectjweaver-1.6.10.jar
/foo-lib/checkstyle.checkstyle-5.5.jar
/foo-lib/cobertura.cobertura-1.9.4.jar
/foo-lib/cobertura.log4j-1.2.16.jar
/foo-lib/cobertura.oro-2.0.8.jar
/foo-lib/commons-codec.commons-codec-1.4.jar
/foo-lib/commons-io.commons-io-2.3.jar
/foo-lib/commons-logging.commons-logging-1.1.1.jar
/foo-lib/eclipse.core.contenttype-3.2.0.jar
/foo-lib/eclipse.core.jobs-3.2.0.jar
/foo-lib/eclipse.core.resources-3.2.0.jar
/foo-lib/eclipse.core.runtime-3.2.0.jar
/foo-lib/eclipse.equinox.common-3.2.0.jar
/foo-lib/eclipse.equinox.preferences-3.2.0.jar
/foo-lib/eclipse.jdt.core-3.2.0.jar
/foo-lib/eclipse.jdt.core.manipulation-3.2.0.jar
/foo-lib/eclipse.osgi-3.2.0.jar
/foo-lib/eclipse.text-3.2.0.jar
/foo-lib/findbugs.annotations-1.3.9.jar
/foo-lib/findbugs.bcel-1.3.9.jar
/foo-lib/findbugs.commons-lang-1.3.9.jar
/foo-lib/findbugs.dom4j-1.3.9.jar
/foo-lib/findbugs.findbugs-1.3.9.jar
/foo-lib/findbugs.findbugs-ant-1.3.9.jar
/foo-lib/findbugs.jFormatString-1.3.9.jar
/foo-lib/findbugs.jaxen-1.3.9.jar
/foo-lib/findbugs.jdepend-1.3.9.jar
/foo-lib/findbugs.jsr305-1.3.9.jar
/foo-lib/findbugs.mysql-connector-java-1.3.9.jar
/foo-lib/javancss.ccl-32.53.jar
/foo-lib/javancss.javacc-32.53.jar
/foo-lib/javancss.javancss-32.53.jar
/foo-lib/javancss.jhbasic-32.53.jar
/foo-lib/javancss.serializer-32.53.jar
/foo-lib/jibx.bcel-1.2.2.jar
/foo-lib/jibx.jibx-bind-1.2.2.jar
/foo-lib/jibx.jibx-extras-1.2.2.jar
/foo-lib/jibx.jibx-run-1.2.2.jar
/foo-lib/jibx.jibx-schema-1.2.2.jar
/foo-lib/jibx.jibx-tools-1.2.2.jar
/foo-lib/jibx.joda-time-1.2.2.jar
/foo-lib/jibx.qdox-1.2.2.jar
/foo-lib/jibx.stax-api-1.2.2.jar
/foo-lib/jibx.wstx-asl-1.2.2.jar
/foo-lib/jibx.xbis-jibx-1.2.2.jar
/foo-lib/jibx.xmlpull-1.2.2.jar
/foo-lib/jibx.xpp3-1.2.2.jar
/foo-lib/junit.cpsuite-1.2.5.jar
/foo-lib/junit.junit-4.8.2.jar
/foo-lib/org.apache.httpcomponents.httpclient-4.1.2.jar
/foo-lib/org.apache.httpcomponents.httpcore-4.1.2.jar
/foo-lib/org.apache.ivy.ivy-2.3.0-rc2.jar
/foo-lib/org.testng.testng-5.11.jar
/foo-lib/scm.toolkits.commons-1.0.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
/foo-lib/scm.toolkits.liberty-1.0.0.0-42175.jar
/foo-lib/xalan.xalan-2.7.1.jar
/foo/lib/ant-antlr.jar
/foo/lib/ant-apache-bcel.jar
/foo/lib/ant-apache-bsf.jar
/foo/lib/ant-apache-log4j.jar
/foo/lib/ant-apache-oro.jar
/foo/lib/ant-apache-regexp.jar
/foo/lib/ant-apache-resolver.jar
/foo/lib/ant-apache-xalan2.jar
/foo/lib/ant-commons-logging.jar
/foo/lib/ant-commons-net.jar
/foo/lib/ant-jai.jar
/foo/lib/ant-javamail.jar
/foo/lib/ant-jdepend.jar
/foo/lib/ant-jmf.jar
/foo/lib/ant-jsch.jar
/foo/lib/ant-junit.jar
/foo/lib/ant-junit4.jar
/foo/lib/ant-launcher.jar
/foo/lib/ant-netrexx.jar
/foo/lib/ant-swing.jar
/foo/lib/ant-testutil.jar
/foo/lib/ant.ant-contrib-1.0b3.jar
/foo/lib/ant.jar
/foo/lib/ant.svnkit-1.1.2.jar
/foo/lib/ant.svntask-1.0.8.jar
/foo/lib/asm.asm-3.0.jar
/foo/lib/asm.asm-analysis-3.0.jar
/foo/lib/asm.asm-commons-3.0.jar
/foo/lib/asm.asm-tree-3.0.jar
/foo/lib/asm.asm-util-3.0.jar
/foo/lib/asm.asm-xml-3.0.jar
/foo/lib/aspectj.aspectjmatcher-1.6.10.jar
/foo/lib/aspectj.aspectjrt-1.6.10.jar
/foo/lib/aspectj.aspectjtools-1.6.10.jar
/foo/lib/aspectj.aspectjweaver-1.6.10.jar
/foo/lib/checkstyle.checkstyle-5.5.jar
/foo/lib/cobertura.cobertura-1.9.4.jar
/foo/lib/cobertura.log4j-1.2.16.jar
/foo/lib/cobertura.oro-2.0.8.jar
/foo/lib/commons-codec.commons-codec-1.4.jar
/foo/lib/commons-io.commons-io-2.3.jar
/foo/lib/commons-logging.commons-logging-1.1.1.jar
/foo/lib/eclipse.core.contenttype-3.2.0.jar
/foo/lib/eclipse.core.jobs-3.2.0.jar
/foo/lib/eclipse.core.resources-3.2.0.jar
/foo/lib/eclipse.core.runtime-3.2.0.jar
/foo/lib/eclipse.equinox.common-3.2.0.jar
/foo/lib/eclipse.equinox.preferences-3.2.0.jar
/foo/lib/eclipse.jdt.core-3.2.0.jar
/foo/lib/eclipse.jdt.core.manipulation-3.2.0.jar
/foo/lib/eclipse.osgi-3.2.0.jar
/foo/lib/eclipse.text-3.2.0.jar
/foo/lib/findbugs.annotations-1.3.9.jar
/foo/lib/findbugs.bcel-1.3.9.jar
/foo/lib/findbugs.commons-lang-1.3.9.jar
/foo/lib/findbugs.dom4j-1.3.9.jar
/foo/lib/findbugs.findbugs-1.3.9.jar
/foo/lib/findbugs.findbugs-ant-1.3.9.jar
/foo/lib/findbugs.jFormatString-1.3.9.jar
/foo/lib/findbugs.jaxen-1.3.9.jar
/foo/lib/findbugs.jdepend-1.3.9.jar
/foo/lib/findbugs.jsr305-1.3.9.jar
/foo/lib/findbugs.mysql-connector-java-1.3.9.jar
/foo/lib/javancss.ccl-32.53.jar
/foo/lib/javancss.javacc-32.53.jar
/foo/lib/javancss.javancss-32.53.jar
/foo/lib/javancss.jhbasic-32.53.jar
/foo/lib/javancss.serializer-32.53.jar
/foo/lib/jibx.bcel-1.2.2.jar
/foo/lib/jibx.jibx-bind-1.2.2.jar
/foo/lib/jibx.jibx-extras-1.2.2.jar
/foo/lib/jibx.jibx-run-1.2.2.jar
/foo/lib/jibx.jibx-schema-1.2.2.jar
/foo/lib/jibx.jibx-tools-1.2.2.jar
/foo/lib/jibx.joda-time-1.2.2.jar
/foo/lib/jibx.qdox-1.2.2.jar
/foo/lib/jibx.stax-api-1.2.2.jar
/foo/lib/jibx.wstx-asl-1.2.2.jar
/foo/lib/jibx.xbis-jibx-1.2.2.jar
/foo/lib/jibx.xmlpull-1.2.2.jar
/foo/lib/jibx.xpp3-1.2.2.jar
/foo/lib/junit.cpsuite-1.2.5.jar
/foo/lib/junit.junit-4.8.2.jar
/foo/lib/org.apache.httpcomponents.httpclient-4.1.2.jar
/foo/lib/org.apache.httpcomponents.httpcore-4.1.2.jar
/foo/lib/org.apache.ivy.ivy-2.3.0.jar
/foo/lib/org.testng.testng-5.11.jar
/foo/lib/scm.toolkits.commons-1.0.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
/foo/lib/scm.toolkits.liberty-1.1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
/foo/lib/xalan.xalan-2.7.1.jar
```

Can someone help me understand the problem?

Comment: Please see if [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12041111/junit-throws-java-lang-nosuchmethoderror-for-com-google-common-collect-iterables) helps?

Comment: Thanks @Rao but there is only one version of guava in my classpath and it's supplied by the jenkins artifactory plugin itself...

Comment: Ok, but if you see in the given link there is a way to find all the jars using sample code. May be you want to try that just to be double check?