# NoClassDefFoundError - datastax java driver for Cassandra

Tags: cassandra, pom.xml, noclassdeffounderror, datastax-java-driver

I am currently unable to connect to my cassandra database using the datastax driver. I am getting the following error:

```
com.datastax.driver.core.TransportException: [/127.0.0.1] Unexpected exception triggered (java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.common.collect.ImmutableSet.copyOf(Ljava/util/Collection;)Lcom/google/common/collect/ImmutableSet;)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.Connection$Dispatcher.exceptionCaught(Connection.java:556)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.handleUpstream(SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.java:122)

Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.common.collect.ImmutableSet.copyOf(Ljava/util/Collection;)Lcom/google/common/collect/ImmutableSet;
    at com.datastax.driver.core.DataType.<clinit>(DataType.java:144)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.Codec.<clinit>(Codec.java:31)
```

However, I have included the `guava` artefact in my `pom.xml` as follows:

```
<!-- Datastax driver -->

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.datastax.cassandra</groupId>
        <artifactId>cassandra-driver-core</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.4</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Cassandra -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.cassandra</groupId>
        <artifactId>cassandra-all</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.9</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- guava --<
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
        <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
        <version>15.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

Full `pom.xml`: http://pastebin.ubuntu.com/6358603/

Am I missing a dependency?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the advice of this question: [no such method error: ImmutableList.copyOf()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3126330/no-such-method-error-immutablelist-copyof)

I had to exclude the google collections jar:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.zkoss.zk</groupId>
        <artifactId>zkspring-core</artifactId>
        <version>3.1</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>com.google.collections</groupId>
                <artifactId>google-collections</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

According to [its POM](http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Ccom.datastax.cassandra%7Ccassandra-driver-core%7C1.0.4%7Cjar), version 1.0.4 of `cassandra-driver-core` uses version 14.0.1 of Guava, not version 15.0. I'm guessing you are seeing a version clash. Even if that version difference is not the cause of *this* problem, it might cause other problems.

You do not usually need to include transitive dependencies in POMs, Maven takes care of them for you. Or does your own code use Guava itself?