# Datastax cassandra driver 2.1.6: noClassDefFoundError LoggerFactory

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-2.0, datastax-java-driver

I am stuck with the datastax cassandra driver which is throwing this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/slf4j/LoggerFactory
    at com.datastax.driver.core.Cluster.<clinit>(Cluster.java:63)
    at Main.main(Main.java:13)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:140)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.slf4j.LoggerFactory
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 7 more

Process finished with exit code 1
```

I have imported the library with gradle and I see that org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.5 is in the "External Libraries" tree (I am using Intellij IDEA).

```
group 'com.test'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

apply plugin: 'java'

sourceCompatibility = 1.5

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {

    compile 'com.datastax.cassandra:cassandra-driver-core:2.1.6'
    compile 'org.slf4j:slf4j-log4j12:1.7.5'
    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.11'

}
```

Do you have any idea to fix this ? I have found this post which is close to my problem ([NoClassDefFoundError - datastax java driver for Cassandra](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19768169/noclassdeffounderror-datastax-java-driver-for-cassandra)), but no one have replied correctly.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add as a dependency `org.slf4j:slf4j-log4j12:1.7.5`

Comment: @eVoxmusic can you update how the current `build.gradle` looks like?

Comment: The only explanation is that for some reason the dependency is not considered when running your code. Hopefully someone with better Gradle knowledge can spot the issue.

Comment: You probably right, I saw this error multiple times on others SO posts but they were using Maven. Hope someone can help :)